# What is a Derangement?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-2e

The Chronicles of Darkness core rulebok mentions the following under the Rapture Numina (p.138):

> If the victim fails a Resolve + Supernatural Tolerance roll, she gains a temporary derangement for the entity’s Power in days, in a form that binds her closer to the entity’s wishes.

Looking through the rest of the book I cannot find what is meant by a derangement. I looked through the official FAQ as well but it's not mentioned there either. So I went through some of the other recent Chronicles of Darkness books to try and figure it out. Mage: The Awakening 2nd edition makes no mention of it. Demon: The Descent, Werewolf: The Forsaken 2nd edition and Promethean: The Created 2nd edition all mention it, but the blocks they mention it in are direct copies of the Rapture Numina from the core rulebook (I don't own Vampire: The Requiem 2nd edition, but I reckon that it's in there in the same way as well). Promethean does mention it twice: the second mention is in the context of making an Alchemist (p.262):

> Pyros is not for mortals, however, and alchemists suffer consequences for continued exposure. Every alchemist labors under several persistent Conditions and Derangements, reflecting the way that their bodies and minds bend under the pressure of the Divine Fire. Conditions like Addicted, Disabled, Madness, Mute, and Obsession are particularly appropriate, but the Storyteller should feel free to be creative.

Here it mentions Conditions and Derangements as two seperate things, which would mean that that they are indeed two different things in the Chronicles of Darkness since A: they're both capitalized and are therefore both A Thing and B: since Alchemists are new in the 2nd edition of the game there cannot be a case of blind copy-pasting. Beast: The Primordial mentions it once again as the Numina, but it also does so in the context of a crossover game (p.223):

> In the first edition rules, losing Morality (or its equivalent Trait, such as Humanity, Harmony, or Clarity) was a two-step process: first a degeneration roll, followed by a second roll to see if the character suffered a “derangement.” For some traits, Second Edition replaces this with a single breaking point roll (some traits, such as Humanity in Vampire, use a system more similar to the original).

This would suggest that Derangements are a carry-over from the first edition of the Storytelling System, New World of Darkness. If this is the case though I'm confused as to why Derangements keep being mentioned in the Chronicles of Darkness games, where they are replaced with Conditions. Is there a reason for this that that I keep missing? Or is this a mistake on the part of the writers who accidentally copied it over from the New World of Darkness rules?

Comment: It's funny; the index lists that as the one and only reference to "Derangement" in the book. Good on the indexer, but that's an unfortunate way to commemorate a mistake.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### You're right; it's an error.

In the *[Condition, Dread Power, and Numina PDF](http://www.drivethrurpg.com/product/171574/Chronicles-of-Darkness-Condition-Numina-and-Dread-Power-Cards)*, that word is replaced with "Condition." Use that, instead.